# Fullscreen applications and dual monitor setup ( + cursor grab )

Tags: linux, window-manager, xrandr, multi-monitor

I have dual screen monitor setup.

There are applications (like VLC), where everything works out of the box. If you fullscreen a video, you can use your other screen normally. This is the setup I would expect.

Then there are mostly Linux games and ones you can run via Wine. If you run a fullscreen game, other screen just turns black, violet or flickers like crazy. Moreover, when you exit the game, the second screen is off, so I have to restart X.

Does anyone know how I make this work better? Is this just a matter of those applications not using the appropriate library, or are there more fundamental issues with mutli-monitor support right now?

Added later: Apparently there is no solution, Xorg is just fundamentally broken:

http://www.maketecheasier.com/run-fullscreen-games-in-linux-with-dual-monitors/2010/03/01

Comment: I'm sorry you're having trouble, but this is a very poor quality question. I suggest you edit it to ask how to solve a particular issue by providing system details and what you want to accomplish.

Comment: As for "when will it work" that depends entirely on your particular system. I have several multiple monitor setups and use most programs in full screen. It works nearly perfectly.

Comment: To my mind, you state it with too few details. How could you be helped, if we don't know your distro and version. Is it Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora,to name few but most used ? I personnaly don't see any glitches with my Fedora laptop using for example VLC in full screen on virtualDesktop 1 and running at the same time my web browser in my Virtual Desktop 2 plus some others applications on various additionnal Virtual Desktop. So i'm not exactly at the same level (i.e, I'm not in a Dual Screen configuration) but, at least, can give you some setting of my Distro : % cat /etc/fedora-release Fedora rele

Comment: You edited the question up to a way it no longer represents what I wanted to ask.

Comment: @RokKralj: then re-edit it in a way that asks what you want, fits withing the site's [faq], and doesn't read like a rant. Also don't forget to include your distro, driver(s) and video card details.

Comment: @RokKralj: As Mat mentioned you are free to edit as well to clarify your question. However I would warn that your original question as worded is likely to just get closed as not being a valuable question inside the scope of this site. I would suggest you take into consideration the suggestions you've been given on what you can ask.

Comment: There's a fundamental issue with graphics drivers in general, which is that graphics card makers neither provide good drivers for operating systems other than Windows, nor provide decent specifications that would allow other folks to write a good driver. If you at least said **which graphics card model you have**, we might point you to a better driver version — or tell you to get a different model :(.

Comment: It is a fundamental problem in Xorg, now being addressed by Wayland. Nothing to do with the drivers.

Answer (score 3):

Your color and flicker issues are probably due to a bad driver. You should check with your manufacture and distro to make sure you are running the latest drivers and whatever kernel is recommended as working best with them. Unfortunately some hardware manufactures to not reveal how their hardware works, nor provide good drivers for Linux. This leaves the community in the position of guessing or making do with whatever drivers they do release.

How full screen and multi-monitor issues are handled depends largely on the Window Manager. You might consider trying some different window managers and learning about the different possibilities. Some handle multiple monitors quite differently and you might appreciate some more than others.

Comment: According to this: http://maketecheasier.com/run-fullscreen-games-in-linux-with-dual-monitors/2010/03/01 , there is no solution, except for windowing the game.